# query on multiple fields based on value if not empty included to query but if null remove it from query in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have form search contains:

```
customer id     customer name    email    postal
```

when user fill for example customer name like "john" and email like "hotmail"
I want to search on customer table where custumer_name like "%john%" and email like "%hotmail%".

but when fill customer_name,email and postal

select * from customers where custumer_name like "%john%" and email like "%hotmail%" and postal = 123

what I tried:

```
if ($name != "")    Customer::with('province')->with('country')->with('user')->where("customer_name", "like", "%$name%")->get();

if ($name != "" and $email != "")
  Customer::with('province')->with('country')->with('user')->where("customer_name", "like", "%$name%")->where("email", "like", "%$email%")->get();
```

.
.
.
and so on check all cases but this not efficient solution because if the fields increase i will more IFs.

what is the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

using advanced wheres

```
if (!empty($customer_id)) {
        $customerCollection = $customerCollection->where("id","like", "%$customer_id%");
     }

     if (!empty($name)) {       
        $customerCollection = $customerCollection->where(function($q) use ($name){$q->where("first_name", "like", "%$name%")
                                                                        ->orWhere("middle_name", "like", "%$name%")
                                                                        ->orWhere("last_name", "like", "%$name%");});
     }
```